# BST remove node method "cuts off" rest of tree

Tags: java, tree, binary-search-tree

I want to write a method that removes a node from a binary search tree.

This is my method:

```js
public void remove(Node node)
 //Removes a given node and puts one of the nodes below it in its place until it reaches the end
 {
  
  if (node.left != null) //If the node to the left is not empty
  {
   node.value = node.left.value; //Moves up the left node to take its place
   remove(node.left); //Goes to the next node
   if (node.left.right == null && node.left.left == null)
    node.left = null; //Removes the last node at the end of the tree after moving it up
  }
  else if (node.right != null) 
  {
   node.value = node.right.value; //Moves up the left node to take its place
   remove(node.right); //Goes to the next node
   if (node.right.left == null && node.right.right == null)
    node.right = null; //Removes the last node at the end of the tree after moving it up
   
  } 
  
 }
```

The problem is it only works in some cases.

Let's say for example that I enter  60, 70, 65. (Root node is 50)
The tree should look something like

```
   50
  /  \
     60
    /   \
        70
       /  \
      65
```

Lets then say I choose to remove 60. This seems to work fine at first.
However if I then run my search method, which I trust, returns that 70 has no nodes at any of it pointers.

What I'm assuming is happening is that 70 is set to null before 65 can be moved up. And since 65 is technically no longer connected to the tree, the search method cannot find it.

So something like this:

```
   50
  /  \
     70
    /   \

       /  \
      65
```

The problem is, I don't understand how this could be happening. Especially since it should set the node to null if both its pointers point to null, due to the if statements

```
if (node.left.right == null && node.left.left == null)
                node.left = null;
```

and

```
if (node.right.left == null && node.right.right == null)
                node.right = null;
```

Also, if the first if statement is not true (if left != null), shouldn't it simply continue to the "else" (and remove the right one) insted?

Any suggestions or tips are very welcome.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and separate the BST code from the Swing code. Write unit tests for your BST and make sure it works correctly, THEN hook it up with the frontend.

Comment: I don't know how to make a tree here but take your original tree and put the 65 where the 60 was. I don't think it is possible to have a tree like you think you have.

Comment: @Marichyasana example's tree is a correct BST; the one that would result from your modification isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic of your removal method is highly flawed. First of all, you're not moving the nodes but copying the values, and this is already incorrect: since any node can have two links, copying just the left or the right link value and then checking if you're at a leaf to eventually remove it is wrong: what if you're not at a leaf? What about the other link you're letting behind? In your case, you'll have the value 65 to the right of 70 in the end: no longer a BST. Remember, the rule is that for any node n, all the nodes in the left subtree must be lesser than n and all the node in the right subtree greater than n.

*And this is also why you can't find 65: it's not because 70 has two null pointers attached to it like you think, but because your search method, when it arrives to 70, since it's bigger than 65, searchs for 65 to the **left** of node 70, and there it finds a null.*

This is the correct and classic Hibbard's algorithm to remove a node in a BST: to delete a node x you have to replace it with its **successor**. Which is its successor? Because x has a right child, its successor is the node with the smallest key in its right subtree. The replacement preserves order in the tree because there are no keys between x.key and the successor's key. We accomplish the task of replacing x by its successor in four steps:

- Save a link to the node to be deleted in t
- Set x to point to its successor min(t.right).
- Set the right link of x (which is supposed to point to the BST
  containing all the keys larger than x.key) to deleteMin(t.right), the
  link to the BST containing all the keys that are larger than x.key
  after the deletion. (To delete the minimum, we go left until finding a node that that has a null left link and then replace the link to that node by its right link)
- Set the left link of x (which was null) to t.left (all the keys that
  are less than both the deleted key and its successor).

[image]